# Iterate a specific custom option

Tags: magento-1.7

Wondering if it was possible in Magento to get a specific custom option and iterate its custom option values.

For example

Custom Option: Size
Values: Small, Medium, Large

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by Custom Options in Product Page...

Comment: Could you elaborate on this further? Maybe provide a code snippet as guidance.